# Invalid Operation On An ANSI DATETIME (Subtracting one timestamp from another in Teradata)

Tags: sql, datetime, teradata

I would like to create a WHERE condition to return results where only 1 day has passed between two timestamps. I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM RDMAVWSANDBOX.VwNIMEventFct
INNER JOIN VwNIMUserDim ON VwNIMUserDim.NIM_USER_ID = VwNIMEventFct.NIM_USER_ID
INNER JOIN rdmatblsandbox.TmpNIMSalesForceDB ON TmpNIMSalesForceDB.EMAIL = VwNIMUserDim.USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS
WHERE (CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE - EVENT_TIMESTAMP) =1
```

But the result was an error message "Invalid Operation On An ANSI DATETIME value".

I guess that, looking at the code now, Teradata has no way of knowing whether the "1" in "= 1" is a day, hour or year.

How would I select data where only 1 day has passed between CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE and EVENT_TIMESTAMP?

Same again for 2 days, and 3 days etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both columns are DATEs you can use `=1`which means one day.

For Timestamps you need to tell what kind of interval you want:

```
WHERE (CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE - EVENT_TIMESTAMP) DAY = INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

But i'm not shure if this is what you really want, what's your definition of *1 day*?

**Edit:**

Based on your comment the best way should be:

```
WHERE CAST(CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE AS DATE) - CAST(EVENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) = 1
```

This avoids dealing with INTERVAL arithmetic :-)

Comment: Hi @dnoeth, by 1 day I don't mean 24hours but midnight to midnight. Example, if CONTRACT_EFFECT_DATE time is 23:59 and then the event date is 00:01 then that is one day. Will your answer apply in this sense?

Comment: I tried with your answer and received the same error message?

Comment: This should work and matches your definition, if there's an error it might be `interval field overflow` indication more than 99 days between both timestamps. There are several ways to avoid that error, i'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. Additional comment from my colleague was that I was comparing a timestamp to a date. This seems to fix for that.

Comment: Yep, working with Timestamps and Intervals is tricky, I would prefer easier solutions, too :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Teradata, but I think most versions of SQL have built-in date math functions.  In MSSQL for instance you could do this:

```
...
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE, EVENT_TIMESTAMP) = 1
```

Or if you wanted to make sure 24 hours had passed you could do:

```
...
WHERE DATEDIFF(HOUR, CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE, EVENT_TIMESTAMP) = 1
```

Other SQL's have their own versions of this, and you may have to use 'D' or 'DD' instead of 'DAY' or something (and maybe 'HH' instead of 'HOUR' likewise).